# Количество различных неупорядоченных троек точек

Tags: c#

Всем привет!

Есть задачка: На плоскости задано множество точек А и точка d вне его. Подсчитать количество различных неупорядоченных троек точек a, b, c из А, для которых четырехугольник abcd является параллелограммом.

Я написал код с тремя вложенными циклами, но в них же и запутался. Помогите доработать код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using Tao.OpenGl;

namespace LabRab_5
{// На плоскости задано множество точек А  и точка  d  вне его. 
// Подсчитать  количество  различных неупорядоченных троек точек a, b, c из А,  
// для которых четырехугольник  abcd  является параллелограммом.
class Program
{
    static int[] x, y;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0, k, n, s, j;
        string line;
        double a, b, c, d;
        char[] delimited = new char[] { ' ', ',', '.' };
        Console.WriteLine("Введите количество точек на плоскости");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        x = new int[n];
        y = new int[n];
        using (StreamReader f = new StreamReader("test1.txt"))
        {   //пока файл не пуст, читаем строки
            while ((line = f.ReadLine()) != null)
            {//печатаем, что написали
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                // выделяем числа
                 string[] numbers = line.Split(delimited);
                //занесение в массивы координат
                 x[i] = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
                y[i] = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
                i++;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                    continue;
                for (k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
                {
                    if ((i == k) || (j == k))
                        continue;
                    a = Math.Abs(x[i] - x[k]);
                    b = Math.Abs(x[j] - x[n]);
                    c = Math.Sqrt((x[j] - x[i]) * (x[j] - x[i]) + (y[j] - y[i]) * (y[j] - y[i]));
                    d = Math.Sqrt((x[n] - x[k]) * (x[n] - x[k]) + (y[n] - y[k]) * (y[n] - y[k]));
                    s = 0;
                    if ((y[k] == y[n]) && (y[i] == y[j]) && (a == b) && (c == d))
                        s++;
                    if (s != 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Количество троек:{0}", s);
                    if (s == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Троек нет");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Например, в файле находятся числа:

```
1 0
10 7
9 5
2 5
5 5 
3 3
4 8
6 0
11 10
11 3
8 7
5 3
4 0
```

Ответ: Троек 2

Answer (score 1):

1. для того что бы вам и другим проще было читать код, хорошо было бы указывать коментарии в конце каждой строки с описанием русским языком что вы там делаете, а то когда смотришь на

> ((i == k) || (j == k))

не совсем понимаешь что и с чем сравнивают.

1. Не совсем понятно зачем вы создаете два массива для хранения координат, ведь куда проще  было бы работать с двумерным массивом, из которого бы мы получали сразу пару координат (замечу кстати что существует вероятность что хранилище в которое вы записываете данные (в вашем случае массив) хранит их не упорядоченно, и при запросе первого элемента вы можете обратиться к тому что допустим в середине массива(например словари из Python)). Не стоит забывать что сегодня вы пишете на одном языке а завтра это может быть другой.
2. не вижу где вы тут вообще вводите координаты для той самой 4 точки относительно которой и нужно выполнять вычисления.

ТЕПЕРЬ О ГЛАВНОМ

1. перед началом вычисления, следует учесть что в списке могут дубликаты координат (т.е. несколько раз указана одна и та же точка). А так же что введенные нами координаты точки могут оказать в этом списке. Да в вашем случае это может быть исключением, но хороший программист всегда стремится все продумать заранее, ведь это сэкономить время в будущем(лучше потратить 5 минут сегодня на доработку, чем завтра весь день искать где и что не так работает).
2. Теперь давайте вместе попробуем описать вашу задачу, тогда вам проще будет проще понять что от вас требуется и как это реализовать на вашем языке программирования, лучше и быстрее: Наша задача по сути сводится к поиску 2х одинаковых параллельных отрезков, на плоскости, которые так же могут лежать на одной прямой.
3. далее имея все перечисленное мы можем представить некий код на русском языке:

> (**ЦИКЛ А**)берем по порядку элемент A из множества м  //*(м может быть обычный двумерный массив в котором каждая строка(столбец) хранит координаты одной точки на плоскости)*
>
> вычисляем проекции этого отрезка на оси х и у и будем хранить их в переменных Х и У соответсвенно //*(их можно и не вычислять тут, а следовательно и не заводить новые переменные, но данный вариант уменьшит количество вычислений которые нам бы пришлось произвести)*
>
> (**ЦИКЛ Б**) берем по порядку элемент Б из множества м
>
> (УСЛОВИЕ Б) Если Б не равно А то //*(то есть это не одна и та же точка, ведь множество у нас одно)*
>
> (**ЦИКЛ С**) берем по порядку элемент С из множества м
>
> (**УСЛОВИЕ С**) Если Б не равно С и С не равно А то //*(проверяем не является ли наша новая точка точкой А или С, ведь множество у нас одно)*
>
> (ПРОВЕРЯЕМ) является ли отрезок БС равный отрезку АД через из их проекции на соответсвующие оси  и являются ли они параллельными и не лежащими на одной прямой(если ДА то) признаем наш параллелограмм
>
> (**КОНЕЦ УСЛОВИЯ С и КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА С**)
>
> (**КОНЕЦ УСЛОВИЯ Б и КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА Б**)
>
> (**КОНЕЦ ЦИКЛА А**)

это основной алгоритм... то что до него и после думаю вам и так понятно как написать нужно

П.С. вечером приду домой напишу как это все будет на Python и постараюсь переписать то же самое на ваш C#

на питоне программа получилась у меня такой

```
# функция проверяющая является ли наш 4х угольник параллелограммом
def parallelogram (a,b,c,d):
    if abs(a[0]-d[0])==abs(b[0]-c[0]) and abs(a[1]-d[1])==abs(b[1]-c[1]): # сравниваем 2 отрезка получающиеся из точек
        ad=(a[1]-d[1])/(a[0]-d[0]) #находим коэффициент наклона прямой на которой лежит отрезок AD
        bc=(b[1]-c[1])/(b[0]-c[0]) #находим коэффициент наклона прямой на которой лежит отрезок ВС
        ads=(a[0]*d[1]-a[1]*d[0])/(a[0]-d[0]) #смещение прямой на которой лежит отрезок AD по оси х от начала координат
        bcs=(b[0]*c[1]-b[1]*c[0])/(b[0]-c[0]) #смещение прямой на которой лежит отрезок BC по оси х от начала координат
        if (ad==bc) and (ads!= bcs): # сначала проверяем их на параллельность по угловым коэффициентам, а потом на то не лежат ли отрезки на одной прямой
            return 1

#далее начинаем основной код программы с массивом м[] и точкой d[]

m=[] # список (одномерный массив) в который будем записывать наши координаты
d=[5,10]
count =0

file_name = "file.txt" #путь к файлу
f = open(file_name) #открываем файл
for line in f: #читаем файл построчно до конца
    line=line.strip('\n') # убиваем разделитель в конце строки
    q=[eval(i) for i in line.split(',')] #разбиваем нашу строку на 2 по разделителю (,) и переводим список строк в массив с 2 числами
    if not((q in m) or (q == d)): # координат не должно быть в массиве и это не должна быть точка D
        m+=[q] # добавляем в массив

l=range(len(m)) # определяем длину массива и создаем список вида [0,1,2,3..]

for ai in l[:-2]:           # перебиваем возможные комбинации из 3х точек
    for bi in l[ai+1:]:     # в которых ABC=BCA т.е. [1,2][3,4][5,6]=[5,6][1,2][3,4]
        for ci in l[bi+1:]: #
            if parallelogram (m[ai],m[bi],m[ci],d) or parallelogram (m[bi],m[ai],m[ci],d): #вызываем нашу функцию для проверки (так как только 2 точки из 3 образуют сторону, а последняя диагональ, но необходимо 2 раза пропустить наши координаты черз процедуру проверки, в которой достаточно перемешать все точки (но не A с D или B с C))
                count+=1 #если мы получили параллелограмм то увеличиваем значение счетчика

print ('можно построить',count ,'параллелограмм(а)')
```

ПС. Ну блин и ошибок у меня тут, так что периодически правлю...

И на С# это будет выглядеть примерно так (кстати это мой ХЕЛЛОУ ВОРЛД НА C#)

```
// ну вот если не допустил ни где ошибок при правке, то все примерно должно выглядеть вот так

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Tao.FreeGlut;
using Tao.OpenGl;

namespace LabRab_5
{// На плоскости задано множество точек А  и точка  d  вне его. 
// Подсчитать  количество  различных неупорядоченных троек точек a, b, c из А,  
// для которых четырехугольник  abcd  является параллелограммом.
class Program
{
    static int[] x, y;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0, k, n, s, j, s, m;
        int[] d =  new int[2];
        string line;
        double a, b, c, d;
        float ad,bc,ads,bcs;
        char[] delimited = new char[] { ' ', ',', '.' };
        Console.WriteLine("Введите количество точек на плоскости");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        x = new int[n];
        y = new int[n];
        using (StreamReader f = new StreamReader("test1.txt"))
        {   //пока файл не пуст, читаем строки
            while ((line = f.ReadLine()) != null)
            {//печатаем, что написали
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                // выделяем числа
                 string[] numbers = line.Split(delimited);
                //занесение в массивы координат
                 x[i] = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
                y[i] = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
                i++;
            }
        }

        s=0; // сюда будем записывать то сколько параллелограммов у нас получилось из точек
        d[0]=5; // это координата х нашей точки  Д
        d[1]=10; // это координата у нашей точкм Д

        for (i = 0; i < n - 3; i++)
        {
            for (j = i+1; j < n - 1; j++)
            {
                for (k = j+1; k < n - 1; k++)
                {
                    m=0
                    //a[0]=x[i] a[1]=y[i]
                    //b[0]=x[j] b[1]=y[j]
                    //c[0]=x[k] c[1]=y[k]
                    //d[0]= d[1]= так как этого параметра нет, я оставлю свои буквы
                    if (abs(x[i]-d[0])==abs(x[j]-x[k])) && (abs(y[i]-d[1])==abs(y[j]-y[k]))
                    {
                        ad=(y[i]-d[1])/(x[i]-d[0]);
                        bc=(y[j]-y[k])/(x[j]-x[k]);
                        ads=(x[i]*d[1]-y[i]*d[0])/(x[i]-d[0]);
                        bcs=(x[j]*y[k]-y[j]*x[k])/(x[j]-x[k]);
                        if (ad==bc) && (ads!= bcs)
                            m++;
                    }
                    if (m==0)
                    {
                        //a[0]=x[j] a[1]=y[j]
                        //b[0]=x[i] b[1]=y[i]
                        //c[0]=x[k] c[1]=y[k]
                        //d[0]= d[1]= так как этого параметра нет, я оставлю свои буквы
                        if (Math.Abs(x[j]-d[0])==Math.Abs(x[i]-x[k])) && (Math.Abs(y[j]-d[1])==Math.Abs(y[i]-y[k]))
                        {
                            ad=(y[j]-d[1])/(x[j]-d[0]);
                            bc=(y[i]-y[k])/(x[i]-x[k]);
                            ads=(x[j]*d[1]-y[j]*d[0])/(x[j]-d[0]);
                            bcs=(x[i]*y[k]-y[i]*x[k])/(x[i]-x[k]);
                            if (ad==bc) && (ads!= bcs)
                                s++;
                        }
                    }
                    else s=s+1; 
                }
            }
        }
        if (s != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Количество троек:{0}", s);
        else if (s == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Троек нет");
    }
}
//и думаю тут еще кавычки закрывающейся не хватает которая открывается после namespace LabRab_5 в самом начале
```

Comment: В хорошо написанном коде комментарии не нужны. Переменные должны называться так, чтобы их назначение было ясно из названия. Нетривиальные операции должны быть вынесены в функции с осмысленными названиями.

Comment: @VladD комментарии могут понадобиться для объяснения бизнес-логики) И когда кто-то другой читает ваш код, ему всё равно будет понятнее, если к блокам кода, пусть и с тривиальными операциями, будут пояснения.

Comment: "вы создаете два массива для хранения координат, ведь куда проще было бы работать с двумерным массивом", а с `Point` ещё проще

Comment: @Trymount: Ну, должны быть говорящие сами за себя названия методов, чтобы не пришлось читать комментарии.

Comment: @VladD нашёл-таки пример, в котором комментарии необходимы (но их нет). В цикле не берётся последнее значение массива. Причину столь странного поведения пришлось уточнять у автора, благо он ещё работает.